# how to rotate integer for a given number in java?

Tags: java

How can I "rotate" numbers, without using array or String?

I have a working code, but it needs further optimizationn.

An example: Given the input number `12345` with a rotation length of `2`, the expected output would be `34512`.

My current code:

```
int a=12345;
int n=2;
int count=0;
int tmp=1,t1=1;
int k=1;
int v=a;

for(int i=0;i<=v;i++) {
    count++;
    v/=10;
    tmp*=10;            
}
for(int j=0;j<=count-n;j++) {
    t1*=10;
}
tmp=tmp*10/t1;
k=a%t1;

k=k*tmp+(a/t1);


System.out.println(k);
```

Comment: short tip: rotating is intellectually possibel on number printout, i.e decimal here. Mathematically is imposiible in general case (imagine civilisation with base of 12)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  should be the best place to ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest an algorithm like this:

1. Get your numbers logarithm to base 10 then add 1 to know its number of digits (in your example: `5`)
2. Take a modulus of your rotations by the number of digits as your "effective rotations" (in your example: `2`)
3. Divide by the number of digits minus the number of rotations and round towards zero, to get the rotated digits (in your example: `12`)
4. Take the rest of the division of 3. and multiply it by 10 to the power of the number of rotations (results in `34500` in your example)
5. Add the rotated digits  (results in `34512` in your example)

It's up to you to write the code ;)

PS: And in real life, you should never use an `int` for those operations (limited length, difficult to handle). A `BigDecimal` or a `String` would be much wiser.

Comment: @VigneshKarunakaran slartidan has written pseudo code in his answer (this one to be precise). His pseudo code is just written in words ;) So it is now for you to translate that into java

Comment: @Lino I Think the above pseudo code is stating my same code. :)

Comment: @VigneshKarunakaran and what is not good about that? The algorithm provided by slartidan works. So if your code is equal to that algorithm. Then why bother?

Comment: I can't get it could you provide a local snippet for that algorithm cause i can't see a differ in  here.

Comment: *i can't see a differ in here*. There is **none**

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's only for one direction of moving, but I think it's possible for you to modify it to get the full result

```
private static int rotate(int dig, int n)
{
    int digLen = numDigits(dig);
    int first = (int) (dig / Math.pow(10D, (digLen - n)));

    int last = dig - (int) (first * Math.pow(10D, (digLen - n)));

    int lastInFront = (int)(last * Math.pow(10, n));

    return lastInFront + first;
}

private static int numDigits(int dig)
{
    return (int)Math.log10(dig) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't use Built-in functions

Comment: Quite similar to my answer, but I like the way you calculate `last`!

Comment: @ignesh Karunakaran not using of build-it functions wasn't in your description. Moreover, if you're tailking about optimization - using these methods it's much better, than inventing a bycicle with all those loops.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below statement:

```
a = (int)((a%Math.pow(10,(length-move)))*Math.pow(10,move)+(a-(a%Math.pow(10,(length-move))))/Math.pow(10,length-move));
```

where

`a` is the number itself

`length` is total number of digits

and `move` is number of digits to move in above number

I have used below statement to count the number of digits in a number:

```
for(; temp != 0; temp/=10, ++length);
```

where `temp = a;`

Please find working screenshot below for all possible moves:

[image]

Comment: The one who has given a downvote, request you to please share reason for the same

Comment: I did not downvote - however I would suggest to choose a prettier source code formatting :)

Comment: @VigneshKarunakaran But this is not what you asked for initially.

Comment: @slartidan Agreed.. but as this is in one line no formatter is formatting it :)

Comment: Sorry but i need a code without any math class functions i just need optimize on my code.

Comment: @VigneshKarunakaran there is **no** optimization to your code when you can't use `Math` methods. Period

Comment: Agreed. Using JAVA inbuilt function doesn't  mean your code is not optimized

Comment: No @Lino Math methods should not be used Anyway Thanks for your Try....:)

Comment: @VigneshKarunakaran who says that *Math methods should not be used*?

Comment: That's the rule ...:P

Comment: @VigneshKarunakaran then there is **no** optimization possible, sorry